# Symfony 4 Form posting to a route

Tags: forms, symfony, post, service, symfony4

I have a problem with a form that deletes a doctrine object when posting in Symfony 4.I searched the problem and i only found that i might have to define a service? I am a beginner in symfony so dont blame me please... I am using datatables and the form is in a modal. When i press the delete button in the modal it tries to post to the route but an error comes up:

> Service "request" not found: did you mean "request_stack"? Anyway, the container inside "App\Controller\ItemManagement" is a smaller service locator that only knows about the "doctrine", "form.factory", "http_kernel", "parameter_bag", "request_stack", "router", "security.csrf.token_manager", "session" and "twig" services. Try using dependency injection instead.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteit">Delete Item</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        Are you sure you want to delete this item?

        <form action="{{ path('delete_item')}}" method="POST" id="theform" >

          <input type="hidden" value="" name="itemtodel" id="itemtodel"/>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" form="theform"  class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In **Controller**:

```
/**
     * @Route("/delitem", name="delete_item", methods={"POST"});
     */
    public function deletetheitem(Request $request)
    {
      if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {

        $itemid = $this->get('request')->request->get('itemtodel');

          ... deleting item code...
        }

      }


      return $this->redirectToRoute("item_management", [], 301);


    }
```

The route item_management is in the same controller and works fine. Am i doing it with the wrong way? Please if you have something to suggest i will appreciate it, thanks!!!!

Comment: Did you specified Request class in `use` section of your controller? `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;`

Comment: @EugeneRuban Yes of course, i am using request in the other item_management route also.

Comment: You need to fix line `$itemid = $this->get('request')->request->get('itemtodel');` to `$itemid = $this->request->get('itemtodel');`

Comment: @EugeneRuban I changed it, but the same error comes up. I am using symfony 4 btw sorry i didnot mentioned.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake. Need to change to `$itemid = $request->request->get('itemtodel');`

Comment: @EugeneRuban An error comes up now in this line  $itemid = $request->request->get('itemtodel');  so i think it needs to be as it was?

Comment: You do not need to use $this->get('request') since you already have a request object in the action defenition (Request $request).

Comment: Ok sorry that was my mistake. I am using now $request but was i pass $itemid to twig with a flush to see if the right id comes up, twig outputs a [object Object], Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

try replacing

```
$this->get('request')->request->get('itemtodel')
```

by

```
$request->request->get('itemtodel')
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not need to define any services since everything should work out of the box in the Symfony 4 (if you have not customize a default config).

Second, do not create static html forms in the template. Use Symfony Forms instead (https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html).

Third, you do not need to use request object if there should not be extra checks for query that get the object to delete. If you have not switched off param converter option (see https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html#using-the-paramconverter) of default Symfony 4, delete action could be like that:

```
/**
 * @Route("/delitem/{item}", name="delete_item", methods={"POST"});
 */
public function deleteItemAction(Item $item)
{
    $doctrine = $this->getDoctrine();
    $em       = $doctrine->getManager();
    $em->remove($item);
    $em->flush();

    //process your response
}
```

Comment: The thing is i already have a symfony form in the main route in the same controller that creates an item. I also pass all items in the template so that i can show the user those items with datatables. Is it a good practise if i put another form in the same function(route) for item deletion and render the form in the modal? My other concern is if i use  symfony form should i use a hidden type right?

Comment: You can render and pass as many forms as you want. Also, I'd prefer to delete an item without form. Just delete link (GET request) with custom javascript confirm modal window.

Comment: Ok i see. What about security? Is there a hole or something? Is it ok to use it without form, thus without a token?

Comment: You could make an extra check in your deleteAction at the top (this require a custom business logic): if(!$this->userCanDelete($item)) {throw new AccessDenyedExcepion($message)}. See security section in the Symfony docs.